# Hiding Repeated Row Values in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a table like below

```
 UserName |  Fee  | ReferenceName | Billed 
 ----------------------------------------
 John        200     John            Yes
 Khalid      100     Chintu          No
 Khalid      100     Naga            Yes
 Khalid      100     Sudheer         Yes
 Sathish     200     aaaa            No
 Sathish     200     bbbb            Yes
 Suresh      100     cccc            Yes
```

I want Out Put like Below:

```
 UserName |  Fee  | ReferenceName | Billed 
 ----------------------------------------
 John        200     John            Yes
 Khalid      100     Chintu          No
                     Naga            Yes
                     Sudheer         Yes
 Sathish     200     aaaa            No
                     bbbb            Yes
 Suresh      100     cccc            Yes
```

Repeated Names will not apper second time Here 'UserName' and 'Fee' columns are repeted columns..

Comment: You can try using rank function and for records having  rank>1, you can hide the fields using case statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
    case when RNum=1 then UserName else '' end UserName,
    case when RNum=1 then Fee else '' end Fee,
    ReferenceName,
    Billed 
from(
    select 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by UserName order by UserName) RNum 
    from tbl
)x
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this

```
select 
    case when RANKK=1 then USERNAME else '' end USERNAME,
    case when RANKK=1 then FEE else '' end FEE,
    REFERENCENAME,
    BILLED 
from(
    select 
        A.*, 
        RANK over (partition by USERNAME,FEE order by USERNAME) AS RANKK 
    from MY_TABLE A
)x
```